# Image disappears after applying align-items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to apply **'align-items'** to the flex container, but when I do, **the image disappears**.

I have a container that displays flex. And image inside that is in block using ratio 16/9.

I want to apply **'align-items' to .container** class and expected **the image not to disappear**.

```css
.container {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     background-color: #abbaea;
     width: 500px;
     height: 500px;
     justify-content: center;
}
 .container > div {
     background-color: #fbd603;
}
 .container > div .aspect-ratio-16-by-9 {
     position: relative;
}
 .container > div .aspect-ratio-16-by-9 .media {
     position: relative;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
}
 .container > div .aspect-ratio-16-by-9 > :first-child {
     width: auto;
     max-width: 100%;
}
 .container > div .aspect-ratio-16-by-9 > img {
     max-height: 100%;
}
 .container > div .aspect-ratio-16-by-9::before {
     content: "";
     display: block;
     padding-bottom: calc(100% / calc(16 / 9));
}
 .container > div .aspect-ratio-16-by-9 > :first-child {
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     height: auto;
     max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div>
    <div class="aspect-ratio-16-by-9">
      <img class='media' src='https://i.ibb.co/4S4J60N/tree1000-1.png' />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not simply use `img { aspect-ratio: 16/9 }` instead of all the pseudo with positioning? `.aspect-ratio-16-by-9 img { display: block; width: 100%; aspect-ratio: 16/9 }` works for me...

Comment: I think you can use *background-image* in *<div class="aspect-ratio-16-by-9">* instead of using an image tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you apply `align-items` to the `.container`, it consumes all available space in the horizontal axis and, as a consequence, squeezes the child div to 0 width.

This happens because there is no width defined on the child div.

To fix the problem, add `width:  100%` to the child div.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #abbaea;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; /* NEW */
}

.container>div {
  width: 100%; /* NEW */
  background-color: #fbd603;
}

.container>div .aspect-ratio-16-by-9 {
  position: relative;
}

.container>div .aspect-ratio-16-by-9 .media {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.container>div .aspect-ratio-16-by-9> :first-child {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.container>div .aspect-ratio-16-by-9>img {
  max-height: 100%;
}

.container>div .aspect-ratio-16-by-9::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: calc(100% / calc(16 / 9));
}

.container>div .aspect-ratio-16-by-9> :first-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div>
    <div class="aspect-ratio-16-by-9">
      <img class='media' src='https://i.ibb.co/4S4J60N/tree1000-1.png' />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```